# on_sent_ok >> location.replace was change

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a code snippet that checks whether a user-entered text string is the same as a text string that appears in Database. If the strings are the same - the user is moved to X, if not to Y.

So far it's worked great until contact-form-7 dropped the option to use the on-sent-ok command.

Can anyone help me adjust the code that will work?
The code is written in php widget, we were unable to integrate JS into the code to use other options ...

```
if ($text==$xxxx) {  

  $wpcf7->set_properties( 
    array (
          'additional_settings' => "on_sent_ok: \"location.replace('https://......');\"",
           ) );
     }

else {

      $wpcf7->set_properties( 
    array(      
     'additional_settings' => "on_sent_ok: \"location.replace('https://other...');\"",
         ) );
     }
    $wpcf7->skip_mail = true;

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will work..

```
if ($text==$xxxx) {  
 ?>
 <script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
      location = 'https://www.website.com/';
    }, false );
 </script>
<?php
 }

else {
 ?>
 <script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
      location = 'https://www.website.com/';
    }, false );
 </script>
<?php
 }
```